# Sending info from site in a table

Tags: html, phpmailer

i am working on a website with a contact form, however im wondering how i can receive the info in a table. the code below is what happens when the user hits the post button. 
and i am receiving it like [receiving mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfjrZ.jpg)

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
if( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] != '' ) {

    $name = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-name'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-name'] : ''; //navn
    $email = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-email'] : ''; //epost
    $adress = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-email'] : ''; //epost adresse
    $phone = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] : ''; //telefonnummer
    $datetime1 = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-datetime'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-datetime'] : ''; //dato og tid


    $service = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-service'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-service'] : ''; //1
    $service1 = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-service1'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-service1'] : ''; //2
    $service2 = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-service2'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-service2'] : '';//3
    $message = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-message'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-message'] : '';//kundemeldinger.
    //avhukningsbokser
    $checkbox1 = isset( $_POST['checkbox-1'] ) ? $_POST['checkbox-1'] : '';
    $checkbox2 = isset( $_POST['checkbox-2'] ) ? $_POST['checkbox-2'] : '';

    $subject = isset($subject) ? $subject : 'New Message From Contact Form';

    $botcheck = $_POST['template-contactform-botcheck'];

    if( $botcheck == '' ) {

        $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );
        $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
        foreach( $toemails as $toemail ) {
            $mail->AddAddress( $toemail['email'] , $toemail['name'] );
        }
        $mail->Subject = "Bestilling fra hjemmeside";

        $name = isset($name) ? "Name: $name<br><br>" : '';
            $adress = isset($adress) ? "Adress:        $adress<br><br>" : '';
        $email = isset($email) ? "Phone:                        $email<br><br>" : '';
        $phone = isset($phone) ? "Telefon:                      $phone<br><br>" : '';
        $datetime1 = isset($datetime1) ? "Dato og tidspunkt:    $datetime1<br><br>" : '';
        $service = isset($service) ? "Additional people:        $service<br><br>" : '';
        $service1 = isset($service1) ? "Sorted waste:           $service1<br><br>" : '';
        $service2 = isset($service2) ? "Payment method:         $service2<br><br>" : '';

        //avhukning start
        $checkbox1 = isset($checkbox1) ? "Papp og tekstil: $checkbox1<br><br>" : '';
        $checkbox2 = isset($checkbox2) ? "Metaller og ror og tilsvarende: $checkbox2<br><br>" : '';

        //avhukning stopp
        $message = isset($message) ? "Additional info:          $message<br><br>" : '';

        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>Denne eposten kommer fra bestillingskjema via ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

        $body = "$name $email $phone $datetime1 $service $service1 $service2 $info $checkbox1 $checkbox2<br>$message $referrer";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct a table like this..

For each variable surround the values in `td` and `tr` like below

```
    $name = isset($name) ? "<tr><td>Name</td><td>$name</td></tr>" : '';
    $email = isset($email) ? "<tr><td>Phone</td><td>$email</td></tr>" : '';
```

finally set the build `tr` above inside a `table` and you are good to go. If you need styles, then set `inline` style for `table`.

```
    $body = "<table>$name $email ...</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, seems to be working, going to check out how to do the styles a bit later :)